# Scroll hidden QWidget in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QWidget` which sometimes can be hidden. This `QWidget` handles external event which causes this widget to scroll. The problem is: when this widget is hidden, then scroll is not performed. Simplified example:

```
QWidget* scrollPanel = new QWidget(parent);
scrollPanel->setGeometry(0, 0, 100, 100);
scrollPanel->setStyleSheet("background: blue");
QWidget* item = new QWidget(scrollPanel);
item->setGeometry(20, 20, 20, 20);
item->setStyleSheet("background: white");

// ... hide or show scrollPanel

scrollPanel->scroll(0, -20);
```

if `parent` is hidden or `scrollPanel` is hidden then `scrollPanel->scroll(0, -20);` does nothing. If everything is visible then `scrollPanel->scroll(0, -20);` is working as intended:

```
scrollPanel->show();
scrollPanel->scroll(0, -20); //works
```

and

```
scrollPanel->hide();
scrollPanel->scroll(0, -20); //does not work
```

So, is there a way to scroll `QWidget` if it is hidden?

Comment: you can try a show/hide cycle before and after the scroll.

Comment: Looking on the source there's check on `isVisible` at the beginning of `::scroll` function and it calls `scroll_sys` from `QWidgetPrivate` which is inaccessible by other means, so it looks like sadly the answer is no.

Comment: Can't you "hide" it by overriding paintEvent and drawing nothing?